# How can I change the size of the text in TextComponent using Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, text, flame

How do you change the size of the text in the TextComponent in Flame?  I want to make the text larger

I used the Flame documentation to get this, but I don't know how to modify it for a larger text size (like 20pt vs 14pt).  Also, what is the anchor?

```
final style = TextStyle(color: BasicPalette.darkBlue.color);
final regular = TextPaint(style: style);

TextComponent startText = TextComponent(text: 'test text', textRenderer: regular)
  ..anchor = Anchor.topCenter
  ..x = (width * 0.2)
  ..y = (height - (height*0.5))
  ..priority = 300;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final style = TextStyle(
  color: BasicPalette.darkBlue.color,
  fontSize: 20.0, // Change the font size here
);
final regular = TextPaint(style: style);

TextComponent startText = TextComponent(
  text: 'test text',
  textRenderer: regular,
)
  ..anchor = Anchor.topCenter
  ..x = (width * 0.2)
  ..y = (height - (height * 0.5))
  ..priority = 300;
```

**What's anchor?**

The anchor in Flame's TextComponent determines where the text is positioned relative to its given coordinates (x and y). You can choose from options like top-left, top-center, top-right, center-left, center, center-right, bottom-left, bottom-center, and bottom-right to align the text as you want. Adjust the anchor and position values to position the text as needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).